# Ifluence of street illumination on laser radiation

Tags: laser, noise

Many people have said that the noise that affects laser light is proportional to the square root of the illumination. But I can't find the formula. Can anyone help?

Maybe it has something to do with this: photon (radiation) noise caused by fluctuations in the number of photons emitted by the source and absorbed by the receiver; the mean square value of these fluctuations is proportional to the square root of the number of photons arriving at the receiver

Comment: I think you are correct, but it's hard to tell for sure because there is much left unsaid about the setup, and what is being measured, and what information is wanted from the measurements.

Comment: The term is photon shot noise.  If you point your digital camera at a uniform illumination field you will find each pixel value different.  Yes there is camera read noise but for bright signals it's mostly shot noise.  Noise is Gaussian distribution with 1 sigma equal to root of signal.  Example google "sharpcap shot noise" to see how they handle it in astrophotograhy.

Comment: All light sources have shot noise. A laser has its own shot noise as does a star, sun or street lamp. If your camera gets light from multiple sources add the squares and take the root to get the total noise.

Comment: @garyp I would like to know about the noise that affects the laser beam. This laser beam is needed to irradiate the window glass and receive information from the room. It is obvious that, for example, daylight introduces its own noise into laser radiation, and in cloudy weather it will be a completely different noise.

Comment: @PhysicsDave photon as I understand it, shot noise is more internal noise of the devices themselves, and not external

Comment: No No No .... light has its own noise, statistical noise!!  It is called "photon shot noise".   Yes electronics has noise also!  If you have a strong light signal probably the photon shot noise is <1%.   If your detector is seeing very low light then both the photon shot noise and the electronics noise will be much more noticable.

Comment: @PhysicsDave thanks a lot

Comment: @PhysicsDave Maybe Maybe Maybe.   Light can be considered to be a particle or a wave.  I think that any phenomenon can be described in either picture, even the photoelectric effect.  In the wave picture shot noise is described by the probabilistic nature of the process of detection. A (quantized) excitation of the wave is destroyed while a (quantized) excitation in the detector is created.  Quantum mechanics doesn't allow us to say *when* that process will occur.  All we can say is the probability that it will occur in some time interval.  (But the photon picture is easier to imagine.)

Comment: No problem.  You can google "sharpcap shot noise"  to see how the astronomers calculate their noise and signal.

Comment: @garyp. Yes they should invent a word Prountum that combines probability and quantum.  There is probably just as much probability in generation as in detection of photons.